# Why do I see escaped characters on the terminal?

Tags: process, terminal, emulation, kill, ctrl

Usually `CTRL-C` or `CTRL-D` quits a program. However, once in a while instead of quitting the program, pressing `CTRL-C` just escapes the characters and outputs it to the terminal screen. I've seen this happen multiple times before for different programs: Django, ssh, etc. I've noticed this happens when I've left the terminal for a long period of time.

- Is there a way to revert the `CTRL-C` behavior back to what I would expect?
- And what is the reasoning behind the escaped characters?

Here is an example output of what I mean by escaped `CTRL-C` and other characters:

^C^C^D^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^[^[^D^D^D^D^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z

Comment: This is because the connection to server may have been broken, so your terminal is just echoing what you do instead of being able to show you what the command or the server was responding. The way to get out of ssh in such is to use termination sequence `~ + . + Enter`. Enter may not be always required

Comment: Tarun Lalwani - Ahh interesting. I'll accept this if you write it as an answer (an explanation of what ~ + . + means would be appreciated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the connection to server may have been broken, so your terminal is just echoing what you do instead of being able to show you what the command or the server was responding. The way to get out of ssh in such is to use termination sequence `~ + . + Enter`. Enter may not be always required

Below are the list of SSH escape sequences

```
  ~.  - terminate connection (and any multiplexed sessions)
  ~B  - send a BREAK to the remote system
  ~C  - open a command line
  ~R  - Request rekey (SSH protocol 2 only)
  ~^Z - suspend ssh
  ~#  - list forwarded connections
  ~&  - background ssh (when waiting for connections to terminate)
  ~?  - this message
  ~~  - send the escape character by typing it twice
```

PS: Taken from https://lonesysadmin.net/2011/11/08/ssh-escape-sequences-aka-kill-dead-ssh-sessions/